# Change separator just between specific columns

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to change the separator just between columns 1 and 9. After that, I would like to maintain the original separator.

Those are first lines of my file both when directly reading it and when `od -c file` is executed:

```
#description: evidence-based annotation of the human genome (GRCh38), version 35 (Ensembl 101), mapped to GRCh37 with gencode-backmap
#provider: GENCODE
#contact: gencode-help@ebi.ac.uk
#format: gff3
#date: 2020-06-03
chr1 HAVANA gene 11869 14409 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; hgnc_id "HGNC:37102"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_target_status "overlap";
chr1 HAVANA transcript 11869 14409 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2_1"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id "HGNC:37102"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1_1"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_target_status "overlap";
```

```
0000000   #   d   e   s   c   r   i   p   t   i   o   n   :       e   v
0000020   i   d   e   n   c   e   -   b   a   s   e   d       a   n   n
0000040   o   t   a   t   i   o   n       o   f       t   h   e       h
0000060   u   m   a   n       g   e   n   o   m   e       (   G   R   C
0000100   h   3   8   )   ,       v   e   r   s   i   o   n       3   5
0000120       (   E   n   s   e   m   b   l       1   0   1   )   ,
0000140   m   a   p   p   e   d       t   o       G   R   C   h   3   7
0000160       w   i   t   h       g   e   n   c   o   d   e   -   b   a
0000200   c   k   m   a   p  \n   #   p   r   o   v   i   d   e   r   :
0000220       G   E   N   C   O   D   E  \n   #   c   o   n   t   a   c
0000240   t   :       g   e   n   c   o   d   e   -   h   e   l   p   @
0000260   e   b   i   .   a   c   .   u   k  \n   #   f   o   r   m   a
0000300   t   :       g   f   f   3  \n   #   d   a   t   e   :       2
0000320   0   2   0   -   0   6   -   0   3  \n   c   h   r   1       H
0000340   A   V   A   N   A       g   e   n   e       1   1   8   6   9
0000360       1   4   4   0   9       .       +       .       g   e   n
0000400   e   _   i   d       "   E   N   S   G   0   0   0   0   0   2
0000420   2   3   9   7   2   .   5   _   4   "   ;       g   e   n   e
0000440   _   t   y   p   e       "   t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   b
0000460   e   d   _   u   n   p   r   o   c   e   s   s   e   d   _   p
0000500   s   e   u   d   o   g   e   n   e   "   ;       g   e   n   e
0000520   _   n   a   m   e       "   D   D   X   1   1   L   1   "   ;
0000540       l   e   v   e   l       2   ;       h   g   n   c   _   i
0000560   d       "   H   G   N   C   :   3   7   1   0   2   "   ;
0000600   h   a   v   a   n   a   _   g   e   n   e       "   O   T   T
0000620   H   U   M   G   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   6   1   .
0000640   2   _   4   "   ;       r   e   m   a   p   _   s   t   a   t
0000660   u   s       "   f   u   l   l   _   c   o   n   t   i   g   "
0000700   ;       r   e   m   a   p   _   n   u   m   _   m   a   p   p
0000720   i   n   g   s       1   ;       r   e   m   a   p   _   t   a
0000740   r   g   e   t   _   s   t   a   t   u   s       "   o   v   e
0000760   r   l   a   p   "   ;  \n   c   h   r   1       H   A   V   A
0001000   N   A       t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t       1   1
0001020   8   6   9       1   4   4   0   9       .       +       .    
0001040   g   e   n   e   _   i   d       "   E   N   S   G   0   0   0
0001060   0   0   2   2   3   9   7   2   .   5   _   4   "   ;       t
0001100   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t   _   i   d       "   E   N
0001120   S   T   0   0   0   0   0   4   5   6   3   2   8   .   2   _
0001140   1   "   ;       g   e   n   e   _   t   y   p   e       "   t
0001160   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   b   e   d   _   u   n   p   r   o
0001200   c   e   s   s   e   d   _   p   s   e   u   d   o   g   e   n
0001220   e   "   ;       g   e   n   e   _   n   a   m   e       "   D
0001240   D   X   1   1   L   1   "   ;       t   r   a   n   s   c   r
0001260   i   p   t   _   t   y   p   e       "   p   r   o   c   e   s
0001300   s   e   d   _   t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t   "   ;
0001320       t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t   _   n   a   m   e
0001340       "   D   D   X   1   1   L   1   -   2   0   2   "   ;
0001360   l   e   v   e   l       2   ;       t   r   a   n   s   c   r
0001400   i   p   t   _   s   u   p   p   o   r   t   _   l   e   v   e
```

How can I transform it to:

```
#description: evidence-based annotation of the human genome (GRCh38), version 35 (Ensembl 101), mapped to GRCh37 with gencode-backmap
#provider: GENCODE
#contact: gencode-help@ebi.ac.uk
#format: gff3
#date: 2020-06-03
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; hgnc_id "HGNC:37 102"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_target_status "overlap";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2_1"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id "HGNC:37102"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1_1"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_target_status "overlap";
```

```
0000000   #   d   e   s   c   r   i   p   t   i   o   n   :       e   v
0000020   i   d   e   n   c   e   -   b   a   s   e   d       a   n   n
0000040   o   t   a   t   i   o   n       o   f       t   h   e       h
0000060   u   m   a   n       g   e   n   o   m   e       (   G   R   C
0000100   h   3   8   )   ,       v   e   r   s   i   o   n       3   5
0000120       (   E   n   s   e   m   b   l       1   0   1   )   ,
0000140   m   a   p   p   e   d       t   o       G   R   C   h   3   7
0000160       w   i   t   h       g   e   n   c   o   d   e   -   b   a
0000200   c   k   m   a   p  \n   #   p   r   o   v   i   d   e   r   :
0000220       G   E   N   C   O   D   E  \n   #   c   o   n   t   a   c
0000240   t   :       g   e   n   c   o   d   e   -   h   e   l   p   @
0000260   e   b   i   .   a   c   .   u   k  \n   #   f   o   r   m   a
0000300   t   :       g   f   f   3  \n   #   d   a   t   e   :       2
0000320   0   2   0   -   0   6   -   0   3  \n   c   h   r   1  \t   H
0000340   A   V   A   N   A  \t   g   e   n   e  \t   1   1   8   6   9
0000360  \t   1   4   4   0   9  \t   .  \t   +  \t   .  \t   g   e   n
0000400   e   _   i   d       "   E   N   S   G   0   0   0   0   0   2
0000420   2   3   9   7   2   .   5   _   4   "   ;       g   e   n   e
0000440   _   t   y   p   e       "   t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   b
0000460   e   d   _   u   n   p   r   o   c   e   s   s   e   d   _   p
0000500   s   e   u   d   o   g   e   n   e   "   ;       g   e   n   e
0000520   _   n   a   m   e       "   D   D   X   1   1   L   1   "   ;
0000540       l   e   v   e   l       2   ;       h   g   n   c   _   i
0000560   d       "   H   G   N   C   :   3   7   1   0   2   "   ;
0000600   h   a   v   a   n   a   _   g   e   n   e       "   O   T   T
0000620   H   U   M   G   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   6   1   .
0000640   2   _   4   "   ;       r   e   m   a   p   _   s   t   a   t
0000660   u   s       "   f   u   l   l   _   c   o   n   t   i   g   "
0000700   ;       r   e   m   a   p   _   n   u   m   _   m   a   p   p
0000720   i   n   g   s       1   ;       r   e   m   a   p   _   t   a
0000740   r   g   e   t   _   s   t   a   t   u   s       "   o   v   e
0000760   r   l   a   p   "   ;  \n   c   h   r   1  \t   H   A   V   A
0001000   N   A  \t   t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t  \t   1   1
0001020   8   6   9  \t   1   4   4   0   9  \t   .  \t   +  \t   .  \t
0001040   g   e   n   e   _   i   d       "   E   N   S   G   0   0   0
0001060   0   0   2   2   3   9   7   2   .   5   _   4   "   ;       t
0001100   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t   _   i   d       "   E   N
0001120   S   T   0   0   0   0   0   4   5   6   3   2   8   .   2   _
0001140   1   "   ;       g   e   n   e   _   t   y   p   e       "   t
0001160   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   b   e   d   _   u   n   p   r   o
0001200   c   e   s   s   e   d   _   p   s   e   u   d   o   g   e   n
0001220   e   "   ;       g   e   n   e   _   n   a   m   e       "   D
0001240   D   X   1   1   L   1   "   ;       t   r   a   n   s   c   r
0001260   i   p   t   _   t   y   p   e       "   p   r   o   c   e   s
0001300   s   e   d   _   t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t   "   ;
0001320       t   r   a   n   s   c   r   i   p   t   _   n   a   m   e
0001340       "   D   D   X   1   1   L   1   -   2   0   2   "   ;
0001360   l   e   v   e   l       2   ;       t   r   a   n   s   c   r
0001400   i   p   t   _   s   u   p   p   o   r   t   _   l   e   v   e
```

As you can see, there is a header which I want to maintain exactly the same. After that, I just want to tab separate the first 9 columns. If I do that, after the 9 tab, the rest of the test is going to be part of the first column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `sed s/.../.../` replaces only the first occurrence. Therefore you can repeat this substitution 8 times. Here, we also ignore lines starting with `#`.

In bash, repeating can be done by using the brace expansion `{1..8}` and `printf`.

```
printf -v cmd 's/ /\\t/;%.0s' {1..8}
sed '/^#/!'"{$cmd}" yourFile
```

For plain `sh` use a loop or the long version

```
sed '/^#/!{s/ /\t/;s/ /\t/;s/ /\t/;s/ /\t/;s/ /\t/;s/ /\t/;s/ /\t/;s/ /\t/;}' yourFile
```

Comment: When repeating the same match, you can use `s//\t/` where `//` is shorthand for 'last match'.

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 'if(!/^#/){$c=8; s/ /\t/ while $c--}' ip.txt
```

Note that the above solution wouldn't work if you want to use `\s+` instead of single space, since `\t` will get matched as a `\s` character.

---

If your 9th column is always `gene_id` and it cannot occur anywhere else in the line:

```sh
perl -pe 's/ (?=.*gene_id\s)/\t/g'

# if gene_id can occur in header lines
perl -pe 's/ (?=.*gene_id\s)/\t/g if !/^#/'
```

These solutions can use `\s+` instead of single space since this is using a single substitution command.

Comment: Something like `@F=split;print join "\t",@F[0..8] . join " ",@F[9..$#F]` if you're worried about multiple spaces...  (not syntactically clean)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), gensub() and \S/\s shorthand:

```
$ awk '!/^#/{match($0,/((\S+\s+){8}\S+)(.*)/,a); $0=gensub(/\s/,"\t","g",a[1]) a[3]} 1' file
#description: evidence-based annotation of the human genome (GRCh38), version 35 (Ensembl 101), mapped to GRCh37 with gencode-backmap
#provider: GENCODE
#contact: gencode-help@ebi.ac.uk
#format: gff3
#date: 2020-06-03
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; hgnc_id "HGNC:37102"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_target_status "overlap";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2_1"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id "HGNC:37102"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1_1"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_target_status "overlap"
```

or borrowing [@Sundeeps idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67703600/1745001) then in any awk:

```
$ awk '!/^#/{c=8; while (c--) sub(/ /,"\t")} 1' file
#description:   evidence-based  annotation      of      the     human   genome  (GRCh38),       version 35 (Ensembl 101), mapped to GRCh37 with gencode-backmap
#provider:      GENCODE
#contact:       gencode-help@ebi.ac.uk
#format:        gff3
#date:  2020-06-03
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; hgnc_id "HGNC:37102"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_target_status "overlap";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5_4"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2_1"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id "HGNC:37102"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2_4"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1_1"; remap_num_mappings 1; remap_status "full_contig"; remap_target_status "overlap"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/ /\t/;s/\t/ /9g' file
```

Translate all spaces to tabs, then replace from the 9th tab all tabs back to spaces.