# How to replace only specific spaces in a file using sed?

Tags: sed

I have this content in a file where I want to replace spaces at certain positions with pipe symbol (`|`). I used *sed* for this, but it is replacing all the spaces in the string. But I don't want to replace the space for the 3rd and 4th string.

How to achieve this?

**Input:**

```
test test test test
```

**My attempt:**

```
sed -e 's/ /|/g file.txt
```

**Expected Output:**

```
test|test|test test
```

**Actual Output:**

```
test|test|test|test
```

Comment: Not exact duplicate, but close enough: [Change separator just between specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703405/change-separator-just-between-specific-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the original input doesn't contain any pipe characters, you can do

```sh
sed -e 's/ /|/g' -e 's/|/ /3' file
```

to retain the third white space. Otherwise see other answers.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 's/ /\
/3;y/\n / |/'
```

As newline cannot appear in a sed pattern space, you can change the third space to a newline, then change all newlines and spaces to spaces and pipes.

GNU sed can use `\n` in the replacement text:

```
sed 's/ /\n/3;y/\n / |/'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the 'first space' twice, e.g.

```
sed -e 's/ /|/' -e 's/ /|/' file.txt
```

Or, if you want to specify the positions (e.g. the 2nd and 1st spaces):

```
sed -e 's/ /|/2' -e 's/ /|/1' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` to replace the first and second *one or more* whitespace chunks:

```sh
sed -i -E 's/\s+/|/;s/\s+/|/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/sKHnXq).

*Details*

- `-i` - inline replacements on
- `-E` - POSIX ERE syntax enabled
- `s/\s+/|/` - replaces the first one or more whitespace chars
- `;` - and then
- `s/\s+/|/` the second one or more whitespace chars on each line (if present).

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and use awk, e.g. using any awk in any shell on every Unix box no matter what other characters your input contains:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) sub(/ /,"|")} 1' file
test|test|test test
```

The above replaces all but the last `" "` on each line. If you want to replace a specific number, e.g. 2, then just change `NF` to `2`.